# highchart click event Brakedown browser in iphone

Tags: php, iphone, safari, highcharts

I am working on web dashboard using `PHP, JQUERY, CSS` only in which i have use simple [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) and its also perfectly working on pc  browsers. But in iphone, its work until clicking on chart. when i click on chart it showdown browser and i  must restart browser. After restarting browser it continuous work until clicking on chart.

I am using **IPHONE 4s**  and **safari** browser.

I have also googling but couldn't get result.Is it highchart's Bug or my handset problem?
Please reply me some solutions if anyone have.
Thanx

Comment: Could you send us link to your demo, reproduced as jsfiddle ?

Comment: I haven't it on web so sorry i cant send you link and i have just use simple charts as you can see in highchart demo. its same .

Comment: But we have no inforamtion about your scripts / configuration / data / php solutions and other, so we cannot debug it without any code.

Comment: Okk i got solution it my browser problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not problem in Highcharts but it is possible that some problems are there with you server.I have faced problem like if my webpage opened in iphone or any other phone then my webserver `XAMPP` broken down.

I have Update my **XAMPP** to Newer Version to solve it and now its working fine. So, Check Your  Server Statistics.